# What is the functionality of IncrementalValuesProvider.WithTrackingName(string name)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

In the context of a .net6 incremental source generator, what does the IncrementalValuesProvider.WithTrackingName(string name) method do?

In addition how/when is it intended to be used?

```
[Generator]
public class MyGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
        var incremntalValueProvider = context.SyntaxProvider
            .CreateSyntaxProvider(predicate: (n, c) => { ... }, transform: (s, c) => { ... });

        incremntalValueProvider = incremntalValueProvider.WithTrackingName("Some tracking name");
}
```

With most things when it comes to source generators, I have been able to google and use a bit of trial and error, to figure out how things work.
However with this particular method, those aproaches has not been helpful. In addition it seems like Micrsofts documentation is pretty much out of date since
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md does not even mention the method.

Answer (score 0):

The `WithTrackingName` method is used for unit testing incremental source generators. With it, you can give a name to each step of the pipeline, and after running the generator, you can use that name to check the output (i.e. state) of that particular step.

See this issue for a more complete explanation: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/54832

Here is the example code from the linked issue:

```
class MyGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    ...
}
...

GeneratorDriver driver = CSharpGeneratorDriver.Create(new [] { new MyGenerator().AsSourceGenerator() }, null, null, null, new GeneratorDriverOptions(IncrementalGeneratorOutputKind.None, true));
Compilation comp1 = ...;

// Run the generators once to set up the baseline cached results.
driver = driver.RunGenerators(comp1);

Compilation comp2 = comp1.AddSyntaxTrees(...);

driver.RunGenerators(comp2);

GeneratorRunResult steps = driver.GetRunResult().Results[0];

Assert.Equal(IncrementalStepRunReason.Modified, steps.TrackedSteps["Calculate State"][0].Outputs[0].Reason);

Assert.Equal(IncrementalStepRunReason.Cached, steps.TrackedSteps["Generate Code"][0].Outputs[0].Reason);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at https://www.meziantou.net/testing-roslyn-incremental-source-generators.htm

Briefly, OronDF343 is right.

WithTrackingName allows to record data about the step and access them from the tests

```
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
.....
      var assemblyNameProvider = context.CompilationProvider
        .Select((compilation, cancellationToken) => compilation.AssemblyName)
        .WithTrackingName("AssemblyName");
```

....

```
       [Fact]
       public void Test()
.....
     // Assert the driver use the cached result from AssemblyName and Syntax
        var assemblyNameOutputs = result.TrackedSteps["AssemblyName"].Single().Outputs;
        Assert.Collection(assemblyNameOutputs, output => Assert.Equal(IncrementalStepRunReason.Unchanged, output.Reason));
```